# Product of **ALL** possible value of length?

Tags: geometry

Geometry problem: 
Given a fixed acute triangle $\bigtriangleup{ABC}$ with $\overline{AB}=13$ and $\overline{BC}=7$. $D$ and $E$ are points on sides $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$ respectively such that $\overline{BD}=\overline{BC}$ and angle $\angle DEB= \angle CEB$. Find the product of all possible values of the length of $\overline{AE}$.

The image of the triangle is not given but my teacher gave the image to us as a hint. At the end of the course he even gave us the solution but there was a point I did not understand. I got the answer and the solution. I look forward to seeing other solutions, please.

Solution: Method of false position, 2 cases provided.

Case 1: $\bigtriangleup{BED}$ $\cong$ $\bigtriangleup{BEC}$

$\angle{DBE}=\angle{DBE}$ (corr. $\angle$s, $\cong$$\bigtriangleup$s)

$AE\over{EC}$=$AB\over{BC}$=$13\over{7}$ ($\angle$ bisector thm)

AE=${13\overline{AC}}\over13+7$=${13\overline{AC}}\over20$

Case 2: $\bigtriangleup{BED}$ $\cong$ $\bigtriangleup{BEC}$ is false

B,C,E,D are concyclic. (????)

$\overline{AD}\times\overline{AB}=\overline{AE}\times\overline{AC}$ (????)

$6\times13=\overline{AE}\times\overline{AC}$

$\overline{AE}$$=$${78}\over\overline{AC}$

Product of possible cases=

## ${78}\over\overline{AC}$$\times$${13\overline{AC}}\over20$

=50.7 units

The parts I dont understand:

1. Why is B,C,E,D concyclic if the triangles are not congruent?
2. What is that property of cyclic quadrilateral?

I also hope to see new solutions pop out!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: If you know the solution, you are allowed to answer your own question, just type it down here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you have two triangles that have two pairs of equal sides and a pair of equal angles ($BE$ is shared, $BC = BD, \angle CEB = \angle DEB$), but the triangles do not have to be congruent. By the sine rule, $\sin \angle BCE = \sin \angle BDE$, hence those angles are either equal or supplementary.

Case 1 is when $\angle BCE = \angle BDE$, then $BE$ is the bisector of $\angle ABC$.

Case 2 is when $\angle BCE + \angle BDE = \pi$. For a cyclic quadrilateral, the sum of the opposite angles is $\pi$, since the sum of the corresponding central angles is $2 \pi$, and an inscribed angle is one half of the central angle. The converse is also true, that is, if the opposite angles are supplementary, then the quadrilateral is cyclic. The last step is applying the [intersecting secants theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_secants_theorem).

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the sin rule makes the angles either equal or supplementary.  My college teacher will never know the solution >:D